# Angular (5) - (click) event function name in model

Tags: angular, generics

I have a hard time explaining the issue to myself with words, so it is darn harder to write it down for you to understand, but I hope you get the idea and have a solution.

I'm currently working on a Angular(5) project where I want to create a generic component which takes an array of my button models as input.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to add a function name to that button model for use in the (click) event. Like

```
export interface ButtonModel{
     value: string;
     functionName: doSomethingOnClick(); <---- problem area
}

//Component holding the buttons
component{
    @Input() buttons: ButtonModel;

    doSomethingOnClick(){
      console.log('this works');
    }
}
```

Which I then should be able to use as

```
<button value="{{btnModel.value}}" (click)="btnModel.functionName"></button>
```

I really don't know if this is even possible. The closest I can get, with my own knowledge is to just hardcode all the buttons and then use an *ngIf to show the ones needed, but being able to just add them dynamically would be a lot smarter.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems like you want to use `@Output` for doSomethingOnClick perhaps

Comment: Your interface definition isn't valid TypeScript, Your component has a single ButtonModel names buttons (why the finel s?), but also has a doSomethingOnClick method (why?), and the view tries using a property btnModel that doesn't exist at all. And then you talk about "all the buttons" and being able to show and hide them. So frankly, I have no idea of what you're actually asking here.

Comment: #Explosion Pills: Yeah using an emitter or something like that was going to be the last resort, I was looking for something smarter. It seems that Reza got the solution I was looking for! :-)

#JB Nizet: This was just a late night writeup, where all the unnecessary was omitted and not actual project code to just trying to illustrate my problem statement. I know that this is not working code, but at least Reza got the idea ;-)

Comment: Thank you Anyway though.  I will try to explain my self better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `ButtonModel` to this

```
export interface ButtonModel{
     value: string;
     click(): void; 
}
```

and you can assign it like

```
x = [{
  value:'OK',
  click: () => {console.log('OK')}
},
{
  value:'Cancel',
  click: () => {console.log('Cancel')}
}]
```

and in your component

```
<button value="{{btnModel.value}}" (click)="onClick(btnModel)"></button>

component{
    @Input() buttons: Array<ButtonModel>;

    onClick(model: ButtonModel ){
      model.click();
    }
}
```